# Не понимаю как работает память массива рядков и столбиков. Ошибок нет, но оно работает

Tags: c++, массивы, выделение-памяти

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n=4, m=5, a[n][m+100],i,j,i1,j1,k=0,q1,q2;
   //работает с m+100 и n+100 (хотя должно только с n+100)
   int b[n];
   for (i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       for (j=0;j<m;j++)
       {
           a[i][j]=1+rand()%81;
           printf ("%5d", a[i][j]);

       }
       cout<<endl;
   }
   cout<<endl<<"Ot kakogo do kakogo nomera"; cout<<endl;

   cin>>q1; cout<<endl;
   cin>>q2; cout<<endl;
   for (i1=n-1;i1>=0;i1--)
   {
       if (i1>=q1 && i1<=q2)
       {
               for (j=0;j<m;j++)
           {
               for (i=n-1+k;i>i1;i--)
               {
                   a[i+1][j]=a[i][j];
               }
               a[i1+1][j]=1;
           }
       k++;
       cout<<k<<" "<<i1<<endl;
       }
   }
   for (i=0;i<n+k;i++)
   {
       cout<<endl;
       for (j=0;j<m;j++)
       {
           printf ("%5d", a[i][j]);
       }
       cout<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Не понимаю **как память столбиков влияет на память строк**, то есть программа работает при добавлении памяти к столбикам, но без прибавления памяти к рядкам и оно работает, если ничего не прибавлять оно вылезает за предел, суть работы программы:
**"Дан двумерный массив. Вставьте в него строку из чисел 1, после всех строк с номерами k1–ого до k2–ой."**

Answer (score 0):

Двумерный статический массив `a[n][m+100]` в памяти программы выделяется как один кусок размером `n*(m+100)` элементов. При этом, выход за индексы массива является неопределенным поведением (undefined behaviour - UB). При этом на практике, если операции с элементами массива не выходят за пределы выделенного куска памяти, то краха программы не происходит. Однако данные, находящиеся в массиве, портятся. UB потому и называется неопределенным, что программа может упасть, а может не упасть.
Если бы вы использовали вместо двумерного статического массива массив векторов `vector<vector<int>> a;`, то выход за пределы одной строки давал бы ошибку.
Т.е. в вашем случае вы делаете ошибку, но программа не падает. Хотя и странно, потому что в общем случае код выходит за пределы выделенной памяти.
Правильно увеличивать размерность по строкам - `a[n+100][m]`, т.к. вы добавляете строки из единиц к уже имеющимся строкам.
Раз у вас тег `c++` то вероятно можно пользоваться контейнерами стандартной библиотеки. Используя `vector<vector<int>> a;` работа со строками стала бы гораздо короче, циклов было бы меньше и код понятнее.